What does だけ mean in this context?
彼はいつもの微笑を振り返らせる。不機嫌を装っただけ、そんないたずらな笑みだった。
I'm confused on this usage of だけ.
The narrator couldn't see the person's so he called for him. I think the narrator was worried about the person's humor. The narrator says the other person turns and what was there was a smile. As far I know そんないたずらな笑みだった。 is "mischievous" but what does 装っただけ here mean? "Only dressed in ill humor"? Is it also describing the smile?

This だけ just means "just/only", and it's probably the verb 装う that threw you off. This 装う means "to pretend" rather than "to dress". For example, 病気を装う means "to pretend to be ill", and 幸せを装う means "to pretend to be happy". So 不機嫌を装っただけ means "I just pretended to be in a bad mood", i.e., "I was actually not in a bad mood".

不機嫌を装っただけ、そんないたずらな笑みだった。
"I was only pretending to be in a bad mood!" — It was such a mischievous grin.

